# C++ + how to handle the memory leak when creating process using posix_spawn()

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I got a legacy code that uses [posix_spawn](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html),

```
int posix_spawn(pid_t *restrict pid, const char *restrict path,
                       const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *restrict file_actions,
                       const posix_spawnattr_t *restrict attrp,
                       char *const argv[restrict],
                       char *const envp[restrict]);
```

And *envp* is created from the parent's environment and which is char**.

The method (Let say M1) which creates the *envp* for the child process does the following:

1. It gets the number of strings in environ.
2. Allocate memory using calloc.
3. Then one by one fill the envp using strdup.

The parent process waits (using waitpid) for the child process to terminate.

Now, the question is
will it be good to deallocate the memory acquired for envp once a child process is created using posix_spawn()?

or
after the child process is terminated?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to free the memory once you're done with it. Right after calling `posix_spawn()`, or at least before the function that the spawn is in returns.

Comment: If you are simply duplicating the parent's environment, why not just pass in the parent's `environ`, avoiding allocation and copying and freeing altogether?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @pilcrow, method M1 modifies some strings in the envp for the child process.